# Issue in Image upload Read Native

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, multipartform-data

I am facing issue in upload Image. My function is as following

```
 uploadImage(photo){
    let fData = new FormData();
    fData.append('file', {uri: photo.uri, name: 'image.jpg', type: 'image/jpeg'});
    fData.append('counterUserId',123)
    fetch('http://dymmyurl/addFile',{
      body: fData,mode: 'no-cors',method: 'POST',mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
  headers: {
    'token': AppStorage.getToken(),
    'userid': AppStorage.getUserId(),
    'Mime-Type':'multipart/form-data',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
    "type": "formData"
  }
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
  }
```

When I am using **'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',** then I am getting issue

> org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

but when I will **not use 'Content-Type'** in my code then I am getting

> org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException:
>   Required request part 'file' is not present

My Backend code is

```
@PostMapping("image/add")
public AddPhotoResponse addPhoto(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest httpReq) {
    AddPhotoRequest request = new AddPhotoRequest(file);
    return service.addPhoto(request);
}
```

Comment: There’s a issue in new release https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551

Comment: Check this for resolution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551#issuecomment-615790406

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion , I will try to implement it

Comment: package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fetch-blob worked for me .